# How would i add the probability of a single event being prevented by more than one prevention method combined.

Tags: probability

I was on my Facebook and I got stumped by something that seemed easy. Basically, it was about preventing an illness.
The post essentially read that you have a 99.95% of surviving this illness and if you get the vaccine, you have an additional 95% chance of surviving. Then, it said there was a 194.95% survival chance if you had both. "That's not right," I thought, so I've been trying to figure out how to do the math for about 30 minutes now and I don't think I have the right tools and/or knowledge to do so. Please help so I can go to sleep lol

Comment: It all depends on what is meant by "additional 95% of surviving".  My best guess is that your original probability of death is $0.0005$ and then your revised probability of death after the vaccine is $0.0005 \times 0.05$.

Comment: So the equation would be 0.9995+((1-0.9995)*.95)? Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this easier I will illustrate it by using numbers of people and not by probabilities.

Imagine you have $1,0000,000$ people, you know that $999,500$ of them will survive this illness regardless if they get a vaccine or not, while $500$ of them won't survive the illness without a vaccine. You give the vaccine to these $500$ and this vaccine is $95$% effective so $475$ of them will survive (that is $500*0.95$), so in total, out of the million people you had $999,500+475=999,975$ survived so the chance of surviving this illness with a vaccin is $\frac{999,975}{1,000,000}=0.999975$ or in other words $99.9975$%